# When inflating a view in OnCreateView, is it supposed to have correct size right after creation?

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin.android, font-size, layout-inflater

I have a `Fragment` class which I use with `Android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`.

In the `OnCreateView`, that is called by the pager when it needs to display another page, I create a label and I want to dynamically set some font sizes inside that label to be a percentage of the label's height:

```cs
class LabelFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Label, container, false);

        float BigFontSize = v.Height / 1.5f;
        float MediumFontSize = v.Height / 5.0f;
        float SmallFontSize = v.Height / 10.0f;

        // Setting font sizes for the children of v

        return v;
    }
}
```

When I wrote this code my understanding was that `v` will have correct `Width` and `Height` right after inflating.

Indeed, this works on the emulators and on some devices, but on some other devices the label child elements disappear because they get zero font size assigned, which means `v.Height` was zero.

Is this code valid? Is it documented whether the view returned by `Inflate` should have correct dimensions? Should I be taking height from `container` instead, and if so, is it documented that it will be non-null when used with `ViewPager`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the view has not yet been drawn in the `OnCreateView` method. So `Height` will most likely be an unexpected value.

OK, so what can you do to get the height of the view? Use `ViewTreeObserver` to get the `PreDraw` event like:

```
v.ViewTreeObserver.PreDraw += (s, e) =>
{
    // do height calculations here
};
```

Also I noticed you are using font sizes, please make sure you are not using pixel heights for them and use a scaleable unit instead (sp). This is presumably why you are setting font size in the first place.

Comment: Hi,can you please see here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33415509/get-height-width-of-imageview-from-android-support-v4-fragmentalways-return-zer 
i have same problem. Also PreDraw doesnt worked for me ;(. Thanks